# Do I need binlogs with a Percona xtradb cluster?

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, percona-xtradb-cluster

If I am running an XtraDB cluster, with no replication, do I need binlogs?

They're enabled and chewing up disk space. I'm aware I can restrict their number using max_binlog_files, but I'm not sure if I need them at all in a clustered environment. If I don't, I'll turn them off and save some disk space.

Comment: IIRC, you need this for point-in-time restores or ISTs for new machines.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  

Yes, the docs for [point-in-time restores](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.2/innobackupex/pit_recovery_ibk.html]) discuss binlogs, so that must be right.  

I wondered about ISTs, and that sounds plausible, but it looks like the cluster is choosing to do SST rather than ISTs even when the binlogs would cover it, so I suspect there's some other threshold there beyond which it's not worth keeping them.

Comment: adjust your gcache.size - https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/09/08/calculate-correct-size-percona-xtradb-clusters-gcache/

Comment: Ok, so that blog suggests that the binlogs aren't relevant for the IST vs SST decision.

In that case I'm still left wondering if I need them at all in a cluster.

Comment: @EdwardHibbert you don't need to enable binary logging on PXC if you don't need PITR.